# Find Laurent series about $z_0=0$ for $\frac{1}{z-1} -\frac{1}{z+1}$ in $2<|z|<\infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Find Laurent series about $z_0=0$ for $\frac{1}{z-1} -\frac{1}{z+1}$ in $2<|z|<\infty$.

I know how to do this for $|z|>1$ but I don't understand how I should set it up for $|z|>2$.

Here is how I would do it for $|z|>1$.

$\frac{1}{z-1}= \frac{1}{z}\frac{1}{1-1/z}=\frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (\frac{1}{z})^n$

And similarly $\frac{1}{z+1}=\frac{1}{z} \frac{1}{1-(-1/z)} = \frac{1}{z} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{z^n}$

Then subtract the two sums. Is it the same answer for |z|>2?

Comment: I suggest that you show how you developed the LS for $|z|>1$.

Comment: Is it strange to ask how the one for $|z|>1$ would not work for this case?

Comment: If $|z|>1$, then certainly $|z|>2$ also.  So, if we see your solution for $|z|>1$, which is valid for $|z|>2$, then we can glean what your "real" obstacle is.

Comment: I added my process for solving when |z|>1

Answer (score 1):

**HINTS:**

$$\frac{1}{z+b}=\frac{1}{z-c+(b+c)}=\left(\frac{1}{b+c}\right)\,\left(\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{z-c}{b+c}\right)}\right)$$

and

$$\frac{1}{z+b}=\frac{1}{z-c+(b+c)}=\left(\frac{1}{z-c}\right)\,\left(\frac{1}{1+\left(\frac{b+c}{z-c}\right)}\right)$$

Comment: I get what you are trying to do, but you need to change your sign of one of the c's. Since $z+b \neq z-c +(b-c)$

Comment: @frostyfeet You caught that typographical error!  Well done.  I've edited accordingly.